# Why does the code not print a flag when asked to?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here is the code, I want a flag to be printed when the user selects it, but it isn't working - it takes the input, but does not draw anything on the turtle shell. Furthermore, it gives the user the next question, and the turtle window crashes. Additionally, the turtle window opens before the idle shell, which isnt ideal. Lastly, the code prints out 2x what you have inputed (i.e. if you input germany for the german flag it will just print out germany germany on two seperate lines) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#####################################################
# Global Variables and Constants
#####################################################
choice = ""
length = 100
#####################################################
# Imports
#####################################################
import turtle
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
#####################################################
# Subprograms
#####################################################
def displayMenu():
    print("Please choose one of three flags - A German, Armenian, Netherlands flag, or all the flags. ")
def makeRectangle():
   turtle.begin_fill()
   for _ in range(4):
       if _% 2 == 0:# drawing length
           turtle.forward(length * 5)          # Forward turtle by l00 units
           turtle.right(90)           # Turn turtle by 90 degree
       else:         # drawing width
           turtle.forward(length)          # Forward turtle by 400 units
           turtle.right(90)          # Turn turtle by 90 degree
   turtle.end_fill()


    
def drawFlag(colourA, colourB, colourC):
    turtle.home()
    turtle.speed(5)
    length = 50
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    def flag(colourA, colourB, colourC):
        turtle.color(colourA)
        turtle.fillcolor(colourA)
        makeRectangle()
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.color(colourB)
        turtle.fillcolor(colourB)
        makeRectangle()
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.color(colourC)
        turtle.fillcolor(colourC)
        makeRectangle()
        flag()

def makeAllFlags():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    flag()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    colourA = ("#FF0000")
    colourB = ("#00008B")
    colourC = ("#FFBF00")
    flag()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    colourA = "#009900"
    colourB = "#CCCC00"
    colourC = "#ADD8E6"
    turtle.pendown()
    flag()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(180)
    colourA = "#990000"
    colourB = "#FFFFFF"
    colourC = "#004C99"
    flag()




#####################################################
# Main Program
####################################################
welcome = "Welcome to the FLAG printer!\n"        #welcome message

print(welcome)
displayMenu()
userChoice = str(input("Which flag do you want printed: (pls say 'each' for all of them) "))     #asks which flag they want printed
print(userChoice)
countryList = ["german", "germany", "armenia", "armenian", "netherlands", "dutch", "gabon", "gabonese", "each"]


if userChoice.lower() not in countryList:         #validates to make sure they have inputed a correct flag
    msg = "Please choose one of the appropriate countries listed above"                        #validates to make sure they have inputed a correct flag
    print(userChoice)
elif userChoice == "germany" or userChoice == "german":                     #if decision is german 
    msg = "Printing German Flag....."
    drawFlag("#000000", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00")
elif userChoice == "armenia" or userChoice == "armenian":                   # if decision is armenian
    msg = "Printing Armenian Flag....."
    drawFlag("#FF0000", "#00008B", "#FFBF00")
elif userChoice == "netherlands" or userChoice == "dutch":                  # if decision is dutch
    msg = ("Printing the Dutch Flag.....")
    drawFlag("#990000", "#FFFFFF", "#004C99")
elif userChoice == "gabon" or userChoice == "gabonese":
    msg = ("Printing Gabonese Flag.....")                      # if the decision is gabon
    drawFlag("#009900", "#CCCC00", "#ADD8E6")
elif userChoice == "each":
    msg = ("Printing all four flags.....")
    makeAllFlags()
print(msg)

question = str(input("Do you want to print a second flag? "))    #if the user wants another flag
question.lower()
if question == "yes":
    turtle.clear()                                 #clears the canvas ready for a new flag to be drawn
    turtle.home()
    print(userChoice)
elif question == "no":                                            #if user says no and wants to quit the program
    turtle.clear
    turtle.home()
    print("Thank you - Goodbye!")
```

Comment: *"but does not draw anything"*: this makes me wonder. When did you realise it was not drawing anything. Did you type all this code, and only started testing it when you had typed all this? Normally, a programmer starts with a few lines of code, tests it, and when it works, continues with more... Please provide the *minimal* code to reproduce the problem you have.

Comment: `if userChoice.lower() != countryList` Since userChoice is a string, and countryList is a list, the two will never be equal. You should use `if userChoice.lower() not in countryList` instead.

Comment: Thank you Nick ODell - will do that

Comment: `elif userChoice == "germany" or "german"` This statement will always be true. This is interpreted as `elif (userChoice == "germany") or ("german")`, and "german" is truthy, because it contains more than zero letters. I suggest `elif userChoice == "germany" or userChoice == "german"` instead.

Comment: @trincot did all the testing in a seperate .py file. Then copied and pasted it into this file. Thats when it started not working

Comment: thanks to @NickODell s suggestion the turtle pointer now goes to the right place, and the correct line (selectedcountry is now printing) now shows. However, the flag does not print. The suggestions have also been added to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the code:

1. The `drawFlag` function has the `flag` function declared inside it. So it is never called;
2. The `draw` function should have the indentation with less than 4 spaces;
3. The `draw` function calls the `flag` function without any arguments;
4. There's a missing `while True:` to keep the turtle drawing the next flag if asked `yes`;

I've fixed those issues and also positioned the flags to not overlap each other when asked to draw all of them.

This is the result:

[image]

```py
#####################################################
# Global Variables and Constants
#####################################################
choice = ""
length = 100
#####################################################
# Imports
#####################################################
import turtle
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
#####################################################
# Subprograms
#####################################################
def displayMenu():
    print("Please choose one of three flags - A German, Armenian, Netherlands flag, or all the flags. ")
def makeRectangle():
   turtle.begin_fill()
   for _ in range(4):
       if _% 2 == 0:# drawing length
           turtle.forward(length * 5)          # Forward turtle by l00 units
           turtle.right(90)           # Turn turtle by 90 degree
       else:         # drawing width
           turtle.forward(length)          # Forward turtle by 400 units
           turtle.right(90)          # Turn turtle by 90 degree
   turtle.end_fill()



def drawFlag(colourA, colourB, colourC):
    # turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.speed(5)
    length = 50
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    flag(colourA, colourB, colourC)

def flag(colourA, colourB, colourC):
    turtle.color(colourA)
    turtle.fillcolor(colourA)
    makeRectangle()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.color(colourB)
    turtle.fillcolor(colourB)
    makeRectangle()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.color(colourC)
    turtle.fillcolor(colourC)
    makeRectangle()

def makeAllFlags():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    colourA = "#000000"
    colourB = "#FF0000"
    colourC = "#FFFF00"
    flag(colourA, colourB, colourC)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.forward(210)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    colourA = ("#FF0000")
    colourB = ("#00008B")
    colourC = ("#FFBF00")
    flag(colourA, colourB, colourC)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.forward(210)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.left(90)
    colourA = "#009900"
    colourB = "#CCCC00"
    colourC = "#ADD8E6"
    turtle.pendown()
    flag(colourA, colourB, colourC)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.left(90)
    colourA = "#990000"
    colourB = "#FFFFFF"
    colourC = "#004C99"
    flag(colourA, colourB, colourC)


#####################################################
# Main Program
####################################################
welcome = "Welcome to the FLAG printer!\n"        #welcome message

print(welcome)
displayMenu()

while True:
    userChoice = str(input("Which flag do you want printed: (pls say 'each' for all of them) "))     #asks which flag they want printed
    print(userChoice)
    countryList = ["german", "germany", "armenia", "armenian", "netherlands", "dutch", "gabon", "gabonese", "each"]


    if userChoice.lower() not in countryList:         #validates to make sure they have inputed a correct flag
        msg = "Please choose one of the appropriate countries listed above"                        #validates to make sure they have inputed a correct flag
        print(userChoice)
    elif userChoice == "germany" or userChoice == "german":                     #if decision is german
        msg = "Printing German Flag....."
        drawFlag("#000000", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00")
    elif userChoice == "armenia" or userChoice == "armenian":                   # if decision is armenian
        msg = "Printing Armenian Flag....."
        drawFlag("#FF0000", "#00008B", "#FFBF00")
    elif userChoice == "netherlands" or userChoice == "dutch":                  # if decision is dutch
        msg = ("Printing the Dutch Flag.....")
        drawFlag("#990000", "#FFFFFF", "#004C99")
    elif userChoice == "gabon" or userChoice == "gabonese":
        msg = ("Printing Gabonese Flag.....")                      # if the decision is gabon
        drawFlag("#009900", "#CCCC00", "#ADD8E6")
    elif userChoice == "each":
        msg = ("Printing all four flags.....")
        makeAllFlags()
    print(msg)

    question = str(input("Do you want to print a second flag? "))    #if the user wants another flag
    question.lower()
    if question == "yes":
        turtle.clear()                                 #clears the canvas ready for a new flag to be drawn
        turtle.home()
        print(userChoice)
    elif question == "no":                                            #if user says no and wants to quit the program
        turtle.clear
        turtle.home()
        print("Thank you - Goodbye!")
        exit()
```